# How to change user admin_color with WP CLI?

Tags: wp-admin, options, wp-cli

I like to know how I can change a users admin color theme with WP CLI.

Answer (score 3):

The admin color theme option is "admin_color". To set an option use the format `--option_name=setting` like so:

```
wp user update 1 --admin_color=blue
```

Where 1 is the ID of the user.

If you prefer to use the user login, you can do that too:

```
wp user update userlogin --admin_color=sunrise
```

The colors should follow the names as you see them in the control panel, except for the default, which is actually 'fresh':

```
fresh (this is labeled 'default' on the Profile page)
light
modern
blue
coffee
ectoplasm
midnight
ocean
sunrise
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `wp user meta list username` for a list of meta information properties.

And update `admin_color` property (like Michelle says) with command `wp user meta update username admin_color newcolor_scheme`.